# How to set Title of images based on image select in android

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, hashmap

I am developing an android app, where I am trying to implement one feature for Image gallary. Now, initially, I want to show some image url with their title name. I am using hashmap for mapping title with their image.I have the model class with two `String` fields url and title. But The problem is I am very new in the development field and now sure how to show the title based on image click. Here is my model Class

```
public class ImageModel implements Parcelable {

String name, url;

public ImageModel() {

}

protected ImageModel(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    url = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<ImageModel> CREATOR = new Creator<ImageModel>() {
    @Override
    public ImageModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ImageModel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ImageModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ImageModel[size];
    }
};

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(url);
  }
}
```

Now the Main activity where I create a Hashmap with image and title to show those into views.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GalleryAdapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

ArrayList<ImageModel> data = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, String> h1 = new HashMap<>();

String[] imgUrls = {"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444090542259-0af8fa96557e?q=80&fm=jpg&w=1080&fit=max&s=4b703b77b42e067f949d14581f35019b",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439546743462-802cabef8e97?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=725&q=50&w=1300",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441155472722-d17942a2b76a?q=80&fm=jpg&w=1080&fit=max&s=80cb5dbcf01265bb81c5e8380e4f5cc1"};
String[] imgNames = {"name1","name2","name3"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //change size according to your size.

        ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
        imageModel.setName(imgNames[i]);
        imageModel.setUrl(imgUrls[i]);
        data.add(imageModel);

    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(MainActivity.this, data);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this,
            new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data", data);
                    intent.putExtra("pos", position);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }));

}
```

}

**GalleryAdapterCode**

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<ImageModel> data = new ArrayList<>();

public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<ImageModel> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View v;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new MyItemHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Glide.with(context).load(data.get(position).getUrl())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .override(200,200)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(((MyItemHolder) holder).mImg);
        ((MyItemHolder) holder).mTextView.setText(data.get(position).getName());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public static class MyItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImg;
    TextView mTextView;


    public MyItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_img);
    }

}
```

}

My XML Class for item list row is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="188dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#7000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_img"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:text="Headline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you want to display image with its name in recycler view?

Comment: Yes. @MurliPrajapati. At previous there is only imahe url. which i loop through , in the way in the comment section code. Now I add title, in hashmap. and want to show seperate title for each images. but do not get how to do it

Comment: @MurliPrajapati I have given my complete code od Activity

Comment: are url and name of images fixed or may change?

Comment: in this case, that urls are fixed, I have 10 url at this moment, and 10 names, according to that

Comment: @MurliPrajapati I have edited my question. Now I am finidind error and app is crashing. Could you please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two `String` arrays one containing image urls and other names in MainActivity.

```
String[] imgUrls = {"url1","url2","url3"};  
String[] imgNames = {"name1","name2","name3"};
```

Iterate over those arrays and create a list of the model class.

```
ArrayList<ImageModel> data = new ArrayList<ImageModel>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //change size according to your size.

        ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
        imageModel.setName(imgNames[i]);
        imageModel.setUrl(imgUrls[i]);
        data.add(imageModel);

    }   
mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(MainActivity.this, data);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Add a `TextView` in your RecyclerView row layout `R.layout.list_item`.
In your adapter use this `TextView` to set name of image.

```
public static class MyItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImg;  
    TextView mTextView; 


    public MyItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_textview);
        mImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_img);
        }
    }  


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Glide.with(context).load(data.get(position).getUrl())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .override(200,200)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(((MyItemHolder) holder).mImg);  
        holder.mTextView.setText(data.get(position).getName());

}
```

Rest of your code will be the same.

Comment: The app is crashing while I run this code. I have given my modified code in the question